# XC8 warning: (107) illegal # directive "foo"

Tags: preprocessor, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, xc8

I have a fair bit of code written to compile under various build systems (e.g. CCS, Visual C, Embarcadero CBuilder, Microchip XCn). Since the various compilers differ in how they define things like inline or interrupt routines, I use #if/#elif/#else constructs to satisfy their requirements. The GCC preprocessor documentation even suggests this as a good use for #if etc.

In the case of my microprocessor build tools, the CCS family of compilers, and XC16 (gcc-based) deal with this just fine, but XC8 insists on looking inside a non-active #if blocks and generating warnings.

For example, the code

```
#ifdef _COMPILER_CCS
   #INT_RDA
   void RDA_ISR(void)
#elif defined (_COMPILER_MCHIP_XC16)
   void __attribute__((__interrupt__(_ISR_SPECIAL_SAVE), __auto_psv__)) _U1RXInterrupt(void)
#elif defined (_COMPILER_MCHIP_XC8)
   void vU1RXInterruptHandler(void)
#else
   #error Problem with defines
#endif
{
...
}
```

generates the warning

```
warning: (107) illegal # directive "INT_RDA"
```

There are hundreds of these warnings generated, making it hard to see legitimate warnings and/or errors.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to make XC8 shut up about things it's not even supposed to be parsing? I cannot find a flag to turn off this warning.

Comment: It has to parse `#foo` directives to find the ending `#elif` / `#else` / `#endif` (and to skip over nested `#if` .. `#endif` constructs).

Comment: ... There's probably a better way, but you could put `#INT_RDA` in a file called `INT_RDA`, then instead of doing `#INT_RDA` in your code, you say `#include "INT_RDA"`.

Comment: @melpomene I agree, but it should not be trying to interpret/process them if the block is inactive. Other compilers manage this just fine. As I mentioned, skipping over code that is inappropriate to a tool chain is explicitly one of the documented uses of the #if directive (at least in gcc documentation).

Comment: @melpomene I have not tested it, but I suspect that the #include method will break the CCS Compiler - it want to see the #INT_DRA directive on the line before the function declaration. Ditto for it's implementation of #inline for inline functions.

Comment: "*it should not be trying to interpret/process them if the block is inactive*" - Catch 22: it has to process them to determine whether the block is inactive.

Comment: It should be possible to disable the warning with a #pragma, but apparently that doesn't work (so I deleted my answer). Clearly, preprocessor blocks need to be scanned even if they are "inactive"; not only does the compiler need to recognize the `#endif`, it needs to recognize nested conditionals. So it is going to be looking at preprocessor directives inside the `#ifdef`, even if it doesn't look at the actual code.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the comments, but this behaviour is specific to XC8. All it has to do is scan for the keywords #if, #elif, #else, and #endif. Blocks that have satisfied conditions are processed further - the rest should just be scanned for the start of the next block. As I said, other compilers manage this just fine.

Comment: @EBlake: and how does it know that `#INT_RDA` is not the beginning of a conditional block terminated with `#END_INT_RDA` or some such? Although I understand your annoyance :) As I said in a now-deleted comment, you should file a bug with XC8 to get the pragma warning disable to work.

Comment: @rici I will file a bug report. Regarding your latest comment: Once an `#if` block is started, the only pre-processor lines that should be processed are either (1) lines contained in an active block (i.e. condition is true) or (2) lines beginning with `#else`, `#elif`, and `#endif`. Every other line should be ignored.

Comment: @EBlake: you also need to look at lines beginning `#if`, `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`, because you need to correctly count `#endif`s on nested conditionals. Which is why I asked how the preprocessor is supposed to know that an unknown preprocessor command is not some form of extended conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I   use macros with     xc8, but use #if
not just #ifdef as it seems to sometimes think undefined 'C'
macros are simply 0. Also I never give a compiler option the value 0.

Bit scary, but I tend to do stuff like:

```
//#define COMP_OPT   1
//#define COMP_OPT   2
#define COMP_OPT   3
```

then in the code

```
#if ( COMP_OPT == 0 )
  #error COMP_OPT NOT DEFINED
#endif

#if ( COMP_OPT == 2 ) 
{
    // code for compile option 2 
    // blah blah
}
#endif
```

That way I don't unintentionally produce code compiled for the wrong option (or none)